# laravel hide pivot data

Tags: php, laravel

How do I hide pivot column data when calling actors relational data the columns I want to hide when calling are "pivot" that contains "movie_id" and "person_id"

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'movies';

    protected $hidden = array('pivot'); // doesn't work

    protected $fillable = [
        'adult',
        'tmdb_id',
        'imdb_id',
        'release_date',
        'original_language',
        'original_title',
        'title',
        'popularity',
        'backdrop_path',
        'poster_path',
        'runtime',
        'tagline',
        'trailer',
        'summary'
    ];

    public function persons() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'movies_pivot', 'movie_id', 'person_id');
    }    

    public function actors() {
        return $this->persons()->wherePivot('job_title', '=', 'Actor')->select('movies_pivot.job_title', 'persons.id', 'persons.name', 'persons.profile_path');
    }
}
```

data returned:

```
"actors": [
{
    "job_title": "Actor",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jaquan Nicolas",
    "profile_path": "asd",
    "pivot": {
        "movie_id": 1,
        "person_id": 1
    }
},
```

Comment: If you are getting a collection back, you should be able to use the `except` method like this: `$movie->actors->except('pivot')`

Answer (score 43):

You need to define:

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
```

On your `App\Person` model, not your `Movie` model.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this function into your model **Movie**

```
    public function toArray()
{
    $attributes = $this->attributesToArray();
    $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $this->relationsToArray());
    unset($attributes['pivot']);
    return $attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please write a function getActorAttributs()** in your Model.php 
then write other one line in your model.php

```
protected $appends = ['actor']; <br/>
protected $hidden  = ['actors']; <br/>

public function getActorAttributs() {
        $persons = $this->persons;
        $output = [];
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            unset($person['pivot']);
            $output[] = $person;
        }
        return $output;
    }
```